# Cannot convert map object into JSON object

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm writing some code in Go lang. I'm new to Go language and I'm stuck at a place. I'm right now having a map object which looks like this

```
count := map[string]int{}
count["Kitchen"] = 1
count["Electronics"] = 1

the output looks like this: map[Electronics:1 Kitchen:1]
```

Now I'm doing

```
answer, _ := json.Marshal(count)
```

The expected answer should look something like this:

```
{"Kitchen": 1, "Electronics": 1}
```

But it is coming like this:

```
[123 34 69 108 101 99 116 114 111 110 105 99 115 34 58 49 44 34 75 105 116 99 104 101 110 34 58 49 125]
```

Comment: `json.Marshal` returns a slice of bytes, to print a readable version of it you can convert it into a string. https://play.golang.org/p/oV-DTEOPRhA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of json.Marshal is an array of bytes. 
If you need to use them as a string, you can just cast them with `string(answer)`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    count := map[string]int{}
    count["Kitchen"] = 1
    count["Electronics"] = 1
    answer, _ := json.Marshal(count)
    fmt.Println(string(answer))
}
```

Execute the code above in the [Playground!](https://play.golang.org/p/pWEp2kHW62b)